# how to round number according to given example number

Tags: perl, numbers, rounding

my variable is 12.2345678

If given `23.45`, then I want to print `12.23`

If given `23.456`, then I want to print `12.234`

Like `printf "%.1f", $var` where `.1` would change according to .2f if given number of `23.45` or .3f if given number of `23.456`

Comment: Your question is not clear.  How do you get from `23.45` to `12.23`?  Do you want to subtract 1 from each digit? That doesn't work for `23.456` and `12.234`.

Comment: edited a bit, see original post. thanks.

Comment: He wants to print the number rounded to the number of decimal places in the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count up the number of digits that follow the decimal, then use that value to construct the printf format.  *ie*

```
$result = sprintf( "%.${count}f", $num );
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` will use an argument for the precision of a field if you specify it with an asterisk, for example `sprintf '%.*2f', 2, 3.14159` results in `"3.14"`.

My solution would be something like this. Note that `12.2345678` *rounded* to three decimal places is `12.235`, not `12.234` as you requested. If you need *truncation* instead then you need a different solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = 12.2345678;

for my $template ('23.45', '23.456') {
  $template =~ /(\d*)\z/;
  my $rounded = sprintf '%.*f', length $1, $var;
  print $rounded, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
12.23
12.235
```